# Failsafe Integration tests don't suspend with debug profile

Tags: maven, debugging, java-11, maven-failsafe-plugin, maven-profiles

I've got a java 11 application that runs my spring-boot based webserver in the maven pre-integration phase test then runs integration tests during the integration test phase via failsafe.

I'm trying to connect a remote debugger to the running tests to track down an issue.

The problem I'm running into is that my maven profile that sets the debug args will cause the server that is started in pre-integration-test to listen for a debugger but failsafe does not suspend as instructed when I activate the profile.

I have the `maven.failsafe.debug` property set via the profile as instructed on the failsafe docs:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/debugging.html

```
    <profile>
        <id>debug-it</id>
        <properties>
            <it.debugArgs>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:40000</it.debugArgs>
            <maven.failsafe.debug>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:40001 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE</maven.failsafe.debug>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

I've updated maven to 3.8.5 and failsafe to the latest, 3.0.0-M6.
A similar profile used to work before migrating my service from java 8 to java 11 a year or so ago.

Note I've also tried manually setting the failsafe debug option directly on the terminal with the same result.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not executing the test from your IDE?

Comment: Because they're integration, not unit, tests, which require running a bunch of external services (kafka, redis, dynamo, several others) via other maven plugins. Supposedly it's possible but I haven't had time to stop and figure it out. I just need it to work

Comment: You should try to set it like this:`mvn -Dmaven.failsafe.debug="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000" verify` (The property is a system property).. second I would reconsider to use something like testcontainers to make such setup within you tests and not via Maven plugins...

Comment: Yes, I tried doing it that way as well before posting the question. I appreciate the test containers suggestion and will look into it in the future but drastic modifications to my test infrastructure are not in the cards at this time